# Given a sharepoint list name, can you use a soap web service to get the List GUID?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

Given a sharepoint list name, is there an easy way using soap web service to get the List GUID?

I am currently having to call `getListCollection` to do it. But this returns everything which is performance constraining now due to size of collection.

And `getList` doesn't work. It just returns the schema.

Comment: GetList does contain the GUID. Get the value of the Name attribute.

Comment: Do a REST call to the GetByTitle endpoint instead of SOAP and use the nometadata option in the Xhr request to slim down the response